# How to change font and lollipop size?

Tags: r, ggplot2

[image]I want to increase the width of the sticks on my lollipop graph, and increase the size of the font of my y-labels. How would I go about doing that?

```
   df_graph2 <- data.frame(
   parameters = c("Cut back spending on food",
            "Used up all or most saving",
            'Increased credit card debt',   
            'Took money out of long-term savings',
            'Borrowed money from family or friends',
            'Pawned or sold possessions'),
  values <- c(34.40,26.00,25.50,14.40,12.70,11.30))
 df_graph2 %>%
 ggplot() + aes(x=parameters, y=values) +
 geom_segment( aes(x=parameters, xend=parameters, y=0, yend=values), color="gray82") +
 geom_point( color="darkorange", size=4.2, alpha=0.9) +
 geom_text(aes(label = paste(values,"%")), hjust = -.3,size=3.8,family="Arial") + 
 expand_limits(y = 100)+
 theme_light() +
coord_flip() +
theme(
plot.margin = margin(1, 1, 4, 1.1, "cm"),
panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),
axis.text.y = element_text(color = 'black'),
panel.border = element_blank(),
axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
axis.title.x = element_blank(),
axis.title.y = element_blank(),
axis.text.x = element_blank(),
panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank()
)
```

Comment: (Posting as a comment because I'm too lazy to test): you already have `size=3.8` in your `geom_text` call: what if you increase that number?  For `geom_segment`, add a `size` or `lwd` specification?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the y axis label size using the size parameter inside the `element_text` call of `theme(axis.text.y` and change the line width of the lollipops with `size =`  inside `geom_segment`

```r
ggplot(df_graph2, aes(parameters, values)) +
  geom_segment(aes(xend = parameters, y = 0, yend = values), 
               size = 2, color = "gray82") +
  geom_point(color = "darkorange", size = 4.2, alpha = 0.9) +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste(values,"%")), hjust = -.3, size=3.8) + 
  expand_limits(y = 100) +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_void() +
  theme(plot.margin = margin(1, 1, 4, 1.1, "cm"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(color = 'black', size = 12, hjust = 1))
```

[image]